# Is zabiha (ritual animal slaughter) valid if the person doing it does not offer salah regurarly?

Tags: salat, dhabihah

Is the [zabiha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhabihah) (prescribed method of ritual slaughter) valid if the person doing it does not offer salah regurarly?  I ask because I heard a person who misses prayers without a valid reason would be considered a kafiir.

Answer (score 3):

No. If the person believes in Allah and His Oneness then he is not kafir. Not offering prayer occasionally or chronically doesn't deem him as kafir/infidel.

Prayer is an obligatory thing, ordained by Allah, for all *Muslims*. Not offering it will make him accountable as a *Muslim*.

Muslim (`p`) [implies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) salah (`q`).

Comment: "Not offering prayer occasionally or chronically doesn't deem him as kafir/infidel." There are quite a lot of scholars who would disagree; ibn Hanbal for example seemingly thought it already renders you a kafir if you purposely omit a small number (I don't remember exactly) of obligatory prayers.

Answer (score 0):

Following an act of kufr doesn't make one a kafir.

Imam Malik said, “If I have 99 reasons to believe a person is a kafir and one to believe he is not, I’ll prefer the latter.”